# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

[image]

This gives me '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' exception when trying to get and show posts on UI that I posted in Firebase real time database.

When I try to delete Iterable the result inside the loop gives null error

Comment: Please post code as code, not an image.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the value that you are receiving is a Map, you can try with snapshot.snapshot.value.entries to see the values that you are recieving

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).